# load/save small data in the cloud (reliably)?

Tags: cloud

There are similar questions:

[Looking for a simple and minimalistic way to store small data packets in the cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281111/looking-for-a-simple-and-minimalistic-way-to-store-small-data-packets-in-the-clo)

Mine is this one:
1) it needs to be reliable 
2) it needs to be secure

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nasuni has a free white paper on the state of cloud storage and you can see the benchmarks of the major cloud providers (Amazon, Azure, Google).  How reliable they are, performance etc.

http://www6.nasuni.com/the-state-of-cloud-storage-in-2013-nasuni-industry-report.html

All major providers provide: free ingress to their cloud, global CDNs, https security based on certificates and 3x/6x redudancy backups. (it is the smaller/cheaper providers to watch out for that do not provide everything mentioned).

All major cloud providers provide high level APIs to their cloud platform.  For sending small data packets.  However, I would be interested in low level API features.  For example, you can have a 40 gig file in Azure and download/manipulate the last 16 bits if you want to rather than downloading the entire file locally.  Another thing that some cloud providers don't all provide is custom domains behind your storage URL that sometimes is important.

The API language if you need to do automation may be important to you.  If you look at Google, they support Java, Python, Go and PHP...if you need .NET Azure has much better support there.

In my opinion, you can't really go wrong with any of the major providers and the best part is to test the upload/storage of Azure/Amazon/Google is really cheap even for a large amount of files.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use object storage on one of the big cloud providers. The key thing to note is to *not* use a CDN and use an API to access your files (all the big providers have clients in Python, Java, .NET, PHP, Ruby, node.js).

Here's a little list:

- Rackspace's [CloudFiles](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files/),
  built off of [OpenStack
  Swift](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Swift).
- Amazon's [Simple Storage Service (S3)](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)
- Least Authority's [Simple Secure Storage
  Service](https://leastauthority.com/)
- Microsoft's [Azure Blob
  Storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/storage/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/http

You can use it either from a JSON or a HTTP posting point of view.

(I recently asked about it: [Temporary cloud storage and sending script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852093/temporary-cloud-storage-and-sending-script))