# Temporary cloud storage and sending script

Tags: bash, scripting, cloud

I'm looking for a way to store small data packages on a temporary place on the cloud, to be lately sent from there and thus erased. It would be also wonderful to be able to create a cloud-script for the sending/erasing task.

This is the scenario: data on the cloud will be sent to different places in different formats, so I need it to be up there until the destination is assigned. When this happens, that particular amount of data will be formatted to the particular destination structure and then sent.

I've been taken a look to several options, and maybe `Openkeyval` could be the best one, but something seems wrong with it because it doesn't let me post anything to any new location.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please put for us what you did up to now

Comment: XD No, no!! No hacking. It's a wireless sensor networks application :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a free and nice solution using Dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/http

Data can be sent and retrieved using curl. Storage is made in the cloud -no need to have a copy of it in any computer-, and can be retrieve from any machine. Just what I was looking for! :D

Comment: By the way, there's an error in the "Tracking deltas from the server" section of that tutorial. The correct form of the curl line syntax should be: curl "https://api.dropbox.com/1/datastores/get_deltas?handle=1PuUJ3DvMI71OYx1gcqWHzzdva2EpF&rev=0" -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>" (in the tutorial, the URL right after the curl command is written without "")

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Amazon S3](https://raamdev.com/2008/using-curl-to-upload-files-via-post-to-amazon-s3/) with the curl command or if you have more freedom about installing additional tools the [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) gives you more power.